# How to reset the conversation if the Microsoft bot is idle for 5 mins and inform user in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

What I want to achieve is to reset session of Microsoft chatbot once the user is idle for 5 minutes and the message the user that he/she is idle for 5 minutes so the session is expired.

I used javascript to render the web chat in frontend of the website.

I implemented the code below but it doesn't work on my end.

[Set Timer Using Microsoft Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54939184/set-timer-using-microsoft-bot-framework)

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
{
   directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
   token: token
}),
  store,
  styleOptions: {

  }
},
document.getElementById('webchat')
```

)

Comment: I'm not sure anyone will be able to help without a more complete example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue open in the Web Chat GitHub repository requesting a sample to reset the conversation after the bot sits idle for a certain period of time. Unfortunately, this sample is blocked by a bug that won't allow us to reset the Redux Store and Direct Line connection in Web Chat to reset the conversation. The development team is working to resolve the issue, and the sample should be done after the next release - v4.6 - in October. You can track the issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/497)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.  I'll get back on this once the next update is released.

Comment: is this issue is fixed in bot framework v4 plase let me know solution in .net